# How write path to file properties?

Tags: java, properties

I wrote a program with two language. I created a file `resources_in.properties`. When I attempted to get properties from the file, I got the error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
> java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:434)     at
> java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:353)   at
> java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:341)    at
> com.rd.java.basic.practice.Helper.getProper(Part5.java:18)    at
> com.rd.java.basic.practice.Helper.main(Part5.java:27)

I think it is because I have an incorrect path to properties.
`resources_in.properties` is located at `MyApp\src\main\resources_in.properties`.
The main class locate `MyApp\src\main\java\com\rd\java\basic\practice\Helper.java`

My code:

```
public class Helper {

    private static String getProper(String lang, String value) {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        InputStream inputStream = Helper.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("./src/main/resources_en.properties");
        try {
            prop.load(inputStream);
        }catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        String word = prop.getProperty(value);
        return word;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(getProper("en","car"));
    }
}
```

Comment: You write `in_properties` three times in your question, but your code says `en_properties`. Maybe that is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to load `./src/main/resources_en.properties` path as a resource. This won't work, resources are referenced not as file system files but as classpath paths. Usually it would be:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
try (InputStream in =
          Helper.class.getResourceAsStream("/resources_en.properties")) {
    prop.load(in);
}
```

however in most build systems resources are placed under `/src/main/resource` while in your case the path is non-standard which can imply problems with packaging the JAR.

It also looks like you are dealing with localized resources due to locale suffix in the file name. Perhaps instead of `java.util.Properties` you should use [`java.util.ResourceBundle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html).